Mirroring actions between Excel Sheets (deleting and adding columns in one sheet, being reflected in the second sheet)
I have an Excel file with two tabs. The tabs are almost identical except the first tab doesn't include any hidden columns but the second tab does. The way that users will be using this file is inputting data in the available columns but also they may want to sometimes delete some columns (and potentially add them back if necessary). All of this will be done by the user in the first tab and should be reflected in the second tab.
What I need is for the information entered by users in the first tab to be reflected in the same places in the second tab. Also, if a user deletes a column (or multiple columns), I need that to be reflected by graying out the corresponding columns in the second tab. If the change is reversed in the first tab, it should also be reversed in the second tab.
I have done some research but so far I was only able to work out the following VBA code which did seem to work very partially:
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim colIndex As Integer
    
    ' Define the worksheets
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    
    ' Check if changes are made in Sheet1
    If Not Intersect(Target, ws1.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' Disable event handling to prevent recursive calls
        
        For Each cell In Target
            If cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then ' Check if the column is not hidden
                colIndex = cell.Column
                ' Gray out corresponding column in Sheet2
                Set rng = ws2.Columns(colIndex)
                rng.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 192, 192) ' Gray color
            End If
        Next cell
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' Enable event handling
    End If
End Sub

I would be grateful for any suggestions or potential sources which may include similar solutions.

Wouldn't simply copying entire cells from sheet1 to sheet2 (creating an exact copy) solve your purpose?

"did seem to work very partially" - what part of that did not work?
